# Is my prof wrong?

Tags: python, mapreduce

I'm solving a problem and something confuses me. In following code isn't

```
counts = mapReduce(lines, mapper=computeWordCounts, reducer=sumUpWordCounts);
```

just wrong? Is that just a pseudocode or such usage is actually possible?

```
def computeWordCounts(line):
    # TODO

def sumUpWordCounts(word, counts):
    # TODO

def mapReduce(data, mapper, reducer):
    # TODO

def test():
    with open('/Users/bgedik/Desktop/zzz.txt') as f:
        lines  = f.read().splitlines()
    counts = mapReduce(lines, mapper=computeWordCounts, reducer=sumUpWordCounts);
    for word, count in counts:
        print word, " => ", count
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? This is certainly possible.

Comment: What do **you** think is wrong with it?

Comment: no its not wrong .... and neither is your professor ...

Comment: because of "mapper=computeWordCounts". It requires "line" parementer, isnt it? also sumUpWordCounts needs two parementers but there is no input paremeters while calling it

Comment: no ... he is not passing the result of a function call ... he is passing a function ... in python functions are first class citizens and can be passed around or assigned to variables at will

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `mapReduce()`. I'm assuming the `mapper` and `reducer` parameters are meant to take functions, and they are then called in `mapReduce` with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: oh right my bad. should i delete this question?

Comment: can you give a basic example to illustrate how such usage is possible with depending functions?

Comment: It may be useful to realize that a function call like `computeWordCounts(line)` is actually two operations in Python: `computeWordCounts` gets a reference to the function, and `(...)` with arguments in it calls the function with those arguments. If you don't put the parentheses after it, the name of a function a reference to a value just like `pi=3.14` or `name = 'Matilda'`. Thus you can pass the function as an argument to another function, and that function can call it (among many other things this lets you do).

Comment: (and actually, functions are just one type of callable object in Python, and all of them can be passed around and treated like any other value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in python functions and classes are first class citizens you can pass them around just like any other variable

```
def square(a_var):
    return a_var ** 2

def apply(value,fn):
   return fn(value)

print apply(5,square)
```

you can also rename them

```
sq = square
print sq(5)
```

there is alot more than this see the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#functions

Answer (score -1):

It's perfectly valid, they're called named arguments. They're a way of skipping arbitrary arguments in the middle of the function all, and still knowing which ones you're actually sending.

This pattern is actually very widespread, from VB6 to C# and more!

Comment: no he is confused about functions being first class citizens

Comment: They don't actually have to be first class citizens for you to be able to get a pointer, just look at C.

Comment: oh I know but then you have only some specific types of functions with special signatures and casting etc....  (python just does all that stuff invisibly to the user) ... this was more stating that the named arguments were not what was hanging up OP